# How to programmatically generate a download token for a private repo file?

Tags: github, curl, github-api

I'm able to download a file from a **private** repo using `curl` and a `token` as:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ..." -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/contents/test.txt" -o test.txt
```

I'm trying to find a way to download the file in a way that i **don't** need to expose the **private** token to the application.

After a lot of research I couldn't find any way to achieve this other than using a token.

When I click on the "download raw file" button on GitHub website,
it generate a link with a token appended to it, something like:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO/e0e8a1743c00ffe05e98f057f34d67eb14beccce/test.txt?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACIMHD2X7BZTCIXWRE4TTMRYZJU3BHA`

This URL is valid only for a short time, but its enough to be able to directly download the file without any additional token.

My idea is to create an API on my DB, and there perform a **curl** request using the **private** token just to get this temporary URL and return it.

Is it possible somehow to **programmatically** find/generate this URL using **curl** and the **private** token?